# Misaligned monospace columns in Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, fonts

Browsing SO, I often find that my Firefox 15.0.1 on Gentoo Linux will fail to render monospace text exactly as monospace. As I haven't seen letters move when syntax highlighting kicks in, I assume that this is not due to Prettify, but instead an effect of the font rendering machinery itself. Using the [Font Finder Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/), I found that the font used is “Liberation Mono” from the 2.00.0 version of [liberation fonts](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/).

I'm not sure whether SO is in any position to fix this, so I won't mark this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). but I'd welcome pointers about how I could fix this for myself. Are any of the fonts with higher priority available for free? Has anyone experienced or heard about similar issues? What can I do to narrow down the list of possible culprits? For which package(s) should I report bugs?

The following screenshot comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12937869/1468366).

[image: Screenshot]